# How to apply Simple Regex Filter to forum signature?

Tags: 7

I'd like [Simple Regex Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_regex_filter) to be applied to [Signatures for Forums](https://www.drupal.org/project/signature_forum) to close the loophole for human post spammers on my drupal 7 forum. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible without your own coding. Currently this module works only on nodes and comments, and this is hardcoded. Given that it is:

> Development status: Maintenance fixes only

you can't hope maintainers will add functionality; they already told they will not.

If you are using Signatures for Forums for Drupal 7, you can try with modules working generically on Entities. As far as I remember [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) could be used for something like that. For Drupal 6, I'm not prepared to even speculate.